# How to reverse the ENTIRE commit history in git?

Tags: git, github, git-commit

My commit history currently looks like, let's say, `A-B-C-D-E-F` with `F` being the HEAD. For some weird reason, I want it to be like `F-E-D-C-B-A` with `A` as HEAD. I can't let others just checkout branch `A` because I want them to see the entire change history from `A` back to `F`. Is there any way I could entirely reverse the commit history in git?

Updated:
(Requirement:
Okay, so, there's this huge codebase that's not on git. All we have is vague documentation about changes made (in text files). We want to put that in git, for future users and ease of maintenance. However, we did not have a proper original version. However, we did have the files like how they look now and the rough change docs. So, we took the current version, reverse applied the forward-changes to make it look like versioned-back. That way, we do have the original version now, but it's HEAD. We want the HEAD to be the last (which was the one we started out with) and also need this history.
)

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  What is the use-case?

Comment: Okay, so, there's this huge codebase that's not on git. All we have is vague documentation about changes made (in text files). We want to put that in git, for future users and ease of maintenance. However, we did not have a proper original version. However, we did have the files like how they look now and the rough change docs. So, we took the current version, reverse applied the forward-changes to make it look like versioned-back. That way, we do have the original version now, but it's HEAD. We want the HEAD to be the last (which was the one we started out with) and also need this history.

Answer (score 2):

That makes absolutely no sense to me... but you can do it using `git rebase -i A^` and then sorting the commits in the text file that you're given to edit.

Comment: You probably mean git rebase -i A^

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: Yes, you're right. `A^` / rebase the commit tree onto the one before.